# Converting T-SQL to Microsoft Access SQL query

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access

I'm having trouble converting T-SQL code from SQL Server to Microsoft Access sql query.  I've added INNER to the JOINs and added in the "dbo_" to the table names.  Do you have any idea what else I could be doing wrong?  Can you not use ON in access sql?  One of the errors says there's a syntax error on join?  Any help would be appreciated! Here is my code:

```
select  distinct
        dbo_Patients.HospitalNumber, 
        dbo_Patients.SocialSecurity, 
        dbo_TextSignals.patientid, 
        dbo_parameters.abbreviation, 
        dbo_parameterstext.text

from dbo_   textsignals 
INNER JOIN dbo_parameterstext
    ON dbo_textsignals.textid=dbo_parameterstext.textid and dbo_textsignals.parameterid = dbo_parameterstext.parameterid
INNER JOIN dbo_parameters
    on dbo_textsignals.parameterid = dbo_parameters.parameterid
INNER JOIN dbo_patients
    on dbo_patients.patientid = dbo_textsignals.patientid

where dbo_textsignals.parameterid in ( 7378, 4640)
and dbo_textsignals.patientid in
                (select distinct patientid 
                 from   signals 
                 where  parameterid = 45 
                        and time  > =  '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
                        and time < '2013-07-01 00:00:00.000') 

order by patientid
```

Comment: Why not create a pass through query in Access?

Comment: *"added in the "dbo_" to the table names."* I don't think you know what `dbo` is.

Comment: I would recommend pass through queries too. Jet SQL needs all joins in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `JOIN` and `ON` in MS Access, however, you need to enclose them in `()` brackets. Something like:

```
FROM (((textsignals 
INNER JOIN parameterstext
        ON textsignals.textid = parameterstext.textid
       AND textsignals.parameterid = parameterstext.parameterid)
INNER JOIN parameters
        ON textsignals.parameterid = parameters.parameterid)
INNER JOIN patients
        ON patients.patientid = textsignals.patientid)
```

Alternatively, you can use the implicit joining style (I recommend the explicit joining above). This can be achieved by listing all your tables in the `FROM` and add all the conditions to the `WHERE`, like this:

```
FROM textsignals, parameterstext, parameters, patients
WHERE textsignals.textid = parameterstext.textid
  AND textsignals.parameterid = parameterstext.parameterid
  AND textsignals.parameterid = parameters.parameterid
  AND patients.patientid = textsignals.patientid
  AND ..... the other conditions you have ....
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to add the brackets but it still says that their is a syntax error in join operation and then it highlights the first dbo_textsignals.

Comment: @user3536337 What is your table name? is it dbo_textsignals or textsignals? I think you need to remove all those dbo_ at the beginning of your table names.

Comment: all the tables begin with dbo_ so i need to include them.. i'm not sure why the explicit joining above wouldn't work?

Comment: @ Perhaps the brackets are wrong, Access is very strict about those brackets. Create a new query in design mode, add those tables to the query, make sure they have the right relationship (the first option is for `INNER JOIN`), add some field to be displayed, switch to SQL mode, copy the joining part, now you can paste that in your query above. I always use this trick to make the query designer do the job for me.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Now, I'm only having issues with the WHERE clause:

Comment: Is it similar with the bracket issue?

Comment: No, `WHERE` does not need any special brackets in Access. What issue are you facing?

Comment: There is a syntax error here:
 (select distinct patientid 
                 from   signals 
                 where  parameterid = 45 
                        and time  > =  '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
                        and time < '2013-07-01 00:00:00.000')

Comment: I got it to work! There was a spacing error. Thank you so much for your help!